# hdf5 c++ write to data failure

Tags: c++, hdf5

The code below prints out error for my 168MB input .h5 file. But works well for my 10MB size file.

```
/* 
 * hdf5write.cpp
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#include "hdf5write.h"

using namespace std;

const H5std_string  DATASET_NAME("geom_data");
const int RANK = 2;
int Hdf5Write(float** & data, size_t & NX, size_t & NY, char* & OutFileName)
{
    H5std_string FILE_NAME(OutFileName);


/* Create a new file using H5F_ACC_TRUNC access,
* default file creation properties, and default file
* access properties.
*/

// H5F: file interface
    H5::H5File file( FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_TRUNC ); // make a file
/*    
* Define the size of the array and create the data space for fixed
* size dataset.
*/
    // unsigned long long     dimsf[2];              // dataset dimensions
    hsize_t dimsf[2];
    dimsf[0] = NX;
    dimsf[1] = NY;

// H5D: datasets interface
    H5::DataSpace dataspace( RANK, dimsf ); // need to know dimensions and size to allocate dataspace
/*
* Define datatype for the data in the file.
* We will store little endian INT numbers.
*/
// H5::IntType datatype( H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT ); // Class IntType     operates on HDF5 integer datatype
                                            // create a integer type     called "datatype", which is 
// H5F: define a float type
    // H5::FloatType datatype( H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT );

    H5::DataSet dataset = file.createDataSet( DATASET_NAME, H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, dataspace );

    dataset.write( data, H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT );

return 0;  // successfully terminated
}
```

The error is found to be at `dataset.write( data, H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, dataspace, dataspace );`

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.11) thread 140007692102656:
  #000: ../../../src/H5Dio.c line 234 in H5Dwrite(): can't prepare for writing data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
```

Previously I always to HDF5 fortran API and always works well. This time I use c++ api.

Comment: I "solved" the problem by referring to the c-version of HDF5 I/O interface.. that gives me much more control of what C++ does and I found  `dataset.write` does not support pointer type like `float** data` as its first argument. The best practice is to write a .c file and mixed with c++.

Comment: The issue using `float data[NX][NY]` is.... stackover flow when you are hitting the uplimit of stack, which is common in my case. Anyway just forget about using c++ wrapper of HDF5 at all! Use C instead, since this is the original version they developed HDF.